# Laravel Registration Key with Validation

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently trying to modify the base Laravel Authentication to include the use of a key created in the database, I've included another field named "key" which I've been able to get the registration to check via a model, the issue is that if the key is incorrectly input I haven't been able to let the user know the key is incorrect.

Current RegistrationController.php

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'key' => ['required'],
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
      $d = Key::where('key', $request->only(['key'])['key'])->first();

      if($d != null){

        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        if ($response = $this->registered($request, $user)) {
            return $response;
        }

        return $request->wantsJson()
                    ? new Response('', 201)
                    : redirect($this->redirectPath());

      }
      else{
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
        return view('auth.register')->withErrors(['key', 'This key was not found']);
      }
    }
```

I've tried to modify the validate method to include `same` but when testing using `same:12345` it looks for a variable called 12345 instead of checking if the key is the same as 12345, how do I change the validation to do what I've done in the register method to check the models instead.

Comment: [Exists Rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-exists) I think you're looking for this.

Comment: I found another stack overflow question relating to exist but I tried to implement `'key' => [  'required', Key::where('key', '=', $data['key'])->exists() ],` Is there something I'm missing since it came up with the error '`..\Validator:validate1 does not exist`, which I assume is it coming back as a 1 for boolean but adding `'exists:'.` before that query comes up with another error SQLSTATE[42P01] which I don't know why I'm getting that error

Comment: I also tried to use the Rule validation as shown in the example with the following: 
`'key' => [  'required', Rule::exists( 'keys' )->where( function( $query ){ $query->where( 'key' , $data[ 'key' ]); }), ]` but unfortunately it errored with `The variable data is not found` and I don't know how to solve that either

Comment: Can you describe what happen or what is issue ?? Is Rule validation not work or what you want to do actual ? So we can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what else to say, have I not explained what I'm trying to achieve in the question above and in the comments what I've tried to use based on the suggested documentation and showed that I haven't been able to get it to work, I believe there's something I'm missing but I don't know how to use this since I'm very new to Laravel, I've even included the error message or error code, I'm trying to add a way to submit a key when registering that checks the database for an existing key and if it's in the db then it registers the user, `keys` being the table name and `key` the col

Comment: You have to use `exists` rule of validator. `'key'=> 'required|exists:keys,key'` Try this and check.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstgood the documentation and thought it was more complicated than it needed to be, this has now worked as intended

Comment: Ok. Laravel official documentation is bery good and easy to understand. Go ahead.